# How do I print a line below another line that is using end=" "

Tags: python, printing

So basically I'm trying to make a hangman game, and my code works fine but I'm getting confused with the end=" "

```
print("Welcome to hangman game!")

import random
words = ["facts", "air", "count", "wack"]
word = random.choice(words)
letters_guessed = []
guesses_left = 9
list(word)


while guesses_left > 0:
    print("The word contains {} letters".format(len(word)))
    for i in word:
        print("_", end=" ")

    user = input("Enter a letter --> ")
```

This is the output I get:

```
Welcome to hangman game!
The word contains 3 letters
_ _ _ Enter a letter -->
```

I want to print "Enter a letter --> " below the "_ _ _".
How can I do that? This is my first time using end=" " so yeah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, you need to use an empty `print()` after the `for` loop:

```
for i in word:
    print("_", end=" ")
print()
```

Or simply, use `sep`. Also, you need to have 2 arguments for sep:

```
print("_"*len(word), sep=" ")
```

Comment: `print(*["_"]*len(word), sep=" ")` must be useful. `print("_"*len(word), sep=" ")` is same as `print("_"*len(word))`

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `\n` to your `input` prompt:

```
user = input("\nEnter a letter --> ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Welcome to hangman game!")

import random
words = ["facts", "air", "count", "wack"]
word = random.choice(words)
letters_guessed = []
guesses_left = 9
list(word)


while guesses_left > 0:
    print("The word contains {} letters".format(len(word)))
    for i in word:
        print("_", end=" ")

user = input("Enter a letter : ")
```

It is more good looking